# Updating a UITableView from a UI button in another View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I want to update a UITableView that is split between a view controller all inside a UITabBar. Is it possible to update the contents of the tableview when a button has been pressed inside the view controller? I don't want to segue into the tableView just continue to update it. The logic of the tableview works with an Array so I need to be able to update that from the external view controller class as well.

Answer (score 2):

You should not try to alter another view controller's views. That violates the principle of encapsulation - an important principle of object-oriented programming.

You should add a method that the other view controller can call.

Make sure the array that serves as the model for the table view is updated, and then send a message to the other view controller telling it to update it's table view.

The view controller that contains the table view would just call `reloadData()` on it's table view in response.

Answer (score 1):

Yes absolutely - as long as you have a reference to the UITableView, you can simply call:

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

**EDIT**

Sorry, I misinterpreted the question. While the above is still valid for multiple view controllers, Duncan C is right about how it's bad practice to access the views of another view controller. For example, say I have a class `ViewController1` and a class `TableViewController1`. Good practice would to have something like the following:

```
class ViewController1: UIViewController {

private var tableView: UITableView!

    func reloadTableView() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}



class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    func doStuff() {
        // some reference to instance of first view controller
        let vc = ViewController1()

        // Do something that requires table view to be reloaded
        vc.reloadTableView()
    }
}
```

Hope this helps!

**EDIT 2**

I've added in what an implementation would like with a UITabBarController:

```
class MyTabBarController: UITabBarController {

    var tableVC: MyTableViewController1?
    var vc2: ViewController2?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.tableVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("table vc storyboard id") as? MyTableViewController1
        self.vc2 = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("vc2 storyboard id") as? ViewController2

        if let vc1 = self.tableVC,
            let vc2 = self.vc2 {

            self.viewControllers?.append(vc1)
            self.viewControllers?.append(vc2)
        }

    }

}


class MyTableViewController1: UIViewController {

    private var tableView: UITableView!
    private var myArray: [AnyObject]!

    func reloadTableView() {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    func addToArray(anObject: AnyObject) {
        self.myArray.append(anObject)
   }
}


class ViewController2: UIViewController {

    var vc2: MyTableViewController1?

    func doStuff() {

        // Do something that requires table view to be reloaded
        vc2?.addToArray(someObject)
        vc2?.reloadTableView()
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. How do I get a reference to the UITableView from another class in swift?

Comment: Yes this definitely helps, the only thing is i'm getting an error when I try to make a reference to the first view controller. "let vc = ViewController1()" Xcode is yelling at me and throwing an error for some reason. Any ideas?

Comment: That line was for illustrative purposes only! How are your view controllers connected? via a segue?

Comment: they are both embedded within a UI TabBar controller. I essentially want to have a button in the first view controller lets call it "Save". every time you press save I want it to append to an array in the second view controller and update the table. So every time the second tab bar item is clicked  you will see the table view with the updated contents.

Comment: Not sure if this helps but when I call the function that calls reloaddata() i'm getting a "EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION" fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: Unfortunatley not, I copied your edits exactly and am still getting a bad access when I try to reload the table view. Its fine when I try to update the Array. it is correctly updated and the size increases by one but the second it hits that reloadTableView is crashes.

Comment: Have you initialised the table view?

Comment: And did you change the storyboard id to ones that you are using?

Comment: Yes, Did all of that. I might try to open up a new project and solve this problem not in the context of my application. Thanks so much for the help. I'll let you know if I need anything else.